# Help on understanding an Improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I've been trying to solve this integral for a while and i can't find the same solution as the one it is given

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{e^x-1}}\left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)^\alpha$$

with $\alpha \gt0$

So for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ I know that it converges only if $\alpha\lt1$

My problems comes with the value as it approaches 0

So far I have done the Taylor expansion at $x=0$ of both $e^x-1$
and $1-\cos(x)$ and I reached the conclusion by the limit comparison that this function behaves as

$$-\int^{\epsilon}_{0}{\frac{\frac{x^{2\alpha}}{2}}{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}}$$

So then I took out the highest order term in the denominator and got

$$-\int^{\epsilon}_{0}{\frac{1}{x^{2-2\alpha}\left(1+o(1)\right)}}$$

Which should only converge if and only if $2-2\alpha\lt1$ so $\frac{1}{2}\lt \alpha$

However the solution is that it converges for every $0\lt\alpha\lt1$

I hope i am clear enough and thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Beside your 2 mistakes on the exponents of $2$ and $x$ (see answer below), there should be no $-$ sign in front of your $\int_0^\epsilon.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x\to0^+,$ a polynomial is not equivalent to its highest order term but to the lowest one, so for $\alpha$ fixed,
$$\frac1{e^x-1}\left(\frac{1-\cos x}{\cos x}\right)^\alpha\sim\frac1x\left(\frac{\frac{x^2}2}1\right)^\alpha=2^{-\alpha}x^{2\alpha-1},
$$
Which is integrable at $0$ iff $2\alpha-1>-1,$ i.e. $\alpha>0.$

You (falsely) derived that $e^x-1\sim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}2.$ You could have similarly derived that $e^x-1=x+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}+o(x^n)\sim_{x\to0}\frac{x^n}{n!},$ which is false as well for every $n\ge2.$